# How to center pagination buttons after table? text-align not working

Tags: html, css

This seems really simple but I am struggling with CSS.
Basically I have a table and after it I use a pagination system to navigate through the table content. The real table has more information, I just used an example to make it look simpler.

I am having a problem trying to center the buttons for the pagination after the table. The text-align property does not seem to be working and I am not sure why.

How can I center the buttons in the center considering the 100% width.

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').after('<div id="nav" class="pagination"></div>');
  var rowsShown = 2;
  var rowsTotal = $('#table tbody tr').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
  }
  $('#table tbody tr').hide();
  $('#table tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
  $('#nav a').bind('click', function() {

    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
    $('#table tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
    css('display', 'table-row').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);
  });



});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}


.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kate</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').after('<div id="nav" class="pagination"></div>');
  var rowsShown = 2;
  var rowsTotal = $('#table tbody tr').length;
  var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
  for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    var pageNum = i + 1;
    $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
  }
  $('#table tbody tr').hide();
  $('#table tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
  $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
  $('#nav a').bind('click', function() {

    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
    var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
    var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
    $('#table tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
    css('display', 'table-row').animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 300);
  });



});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}


.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.pagination a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.pagination a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Sarah</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kate</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue.